# Does CLAHE on Open CV work for floating point pixels?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a set of images in RGB format. The pixel values of which have the dtype of "float64" . But since CLAHE in Open CV support images of the format "uint8", I am forced to convert it into "uint8" format . During this process the image changes into a different one . So if I want to apply CLAHE on the image in LAB space , its of no use . Because the original image is lost. Thank you for your solutions in advance.

Comment: CLAHE is more advanced than HE(histogram equalisation). You can apply HE manually but not sure about CLAHE. There are reasons its based on 8-bit channel image. and ofcourse ur image will change also clearity ll be gone if you convert it.

Comment: Can you please give more insight about what is the reason for it to be applied on 8-bit channel image ?

Comment: try using scikit-image: https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.exposure.html#skimage.exposure.equalize_adapthist it worked for me with fp32 image